# How do I add a number to a value in Python

Tags: python, list

I have to make a seating chart for an assignment for my class and I also need to add the number of absences to each student. How do I add the absence? So far I have this...

```
row1 = ['John', 'Jack', 'James']
row2 = ['Javier', 'Jessica', 'Jane', 'Jose']
row3 = ['Josh', 'Jon', 'Jess']
classroom = [row1, row2, row3]

print (classroom)
```

Comment: What is an absence? How is your data related to 'class', 'student', 'seating', 'absence'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a map describing the student's absences:

```
absences = {'John': 1, 'Jack': 30, 'James': 0, 'Javier': 0, 'Jessica': 3, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to maintain a seperate name:absences dict like

```
 absences = {"name1":12,"name2":123 ... }
```

You may want to store the absences with the name in rows itself.

```
row1 = [('John',1), ('Jack',2), ('James',5)]
```

Or if you may want to have even more data :

```
row1 = [{'name':'John','absences':1}, {'name':'Jack','absences':2}, {'name':'James','absences':5}]
```